# Python error when using Asian characters through IIS

Tags: python, iis

I made this very simple script to test in on browser. setdefaultlanguage was already utf-8

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
f = 'ฟ'
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print f`
```

The moment I added `f = 'some asian text'` I always get an error page with IIS - 502 web server received an invalid response. However, the code itself executes and prints the character just fine if I open it with Python IDLE.

Any help greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Additional information:
The script is run on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and WSGI I believe.

Comment: Please specify the IIS version you are deploying on. Also: how are you serving this Python script (wsgi, cgi,...)? If you change the variable to a simple string like "Hello World", does it work correctly?

Comment: Hi Chris. If I change the text to any english character, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your output of HTTP headers. The headers are terminated by a double linefeed (usually "\r\n\r\n"), while you only have a single one. The web server will treat the asian character as part of the HTTP headers (where it is illegal), and thus throw an error.

Comment: Wow thanks hhaamu. So all I needed was another empty print line right after the header. Thanks very much I was getting very worried ^-^;